# Rspec: method get : show, ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I run test rspec spec/controllers/lost_pets_controller_spec.rb and become error on line **get :show, id: lost_pet**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe LostPetsController, type: :controller do
  let(:lost_pet) { create(:lost_pet) }

  describe "Get #Index" do
    let(:lost_pets) { create_list(:lost_pet, 2) }
    before{ get :index }

    it "populates an array of all lost_pets" do
      expect(assigns(:lost_pets)).to match_array(lost_pets)    
    end

    it "renders index view" do
      expect(response).to render_template(:index) 
    end
  end

  describe 'Get #show' do
    before do
      get :show, id: lost_pet
    end

    it 'assings the requested lost pet to @lost_pet' do
      expect(assigns(:lost_pet)).to eq lost_pet
    end

    it 'renders show view' do
      expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    end
  end
end
```

**lostpetscontroller.rb**

```
class LostPetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_lost_pet, only: [:show]

  respond_to :html

  def index
      @lost_pets = LostPet.all
  end

  def show
    @lost_pet
  end


  private

  def load_lost_pet
    @lost_pet = LostPet.find(params(:id))
  end

  def lost_pet_params
    params.require(:lost_pet).permit([:id, :name, :type_pet, :breed, :gender, :size,
      :colour, :age, :age_unit, :description, :collar_description, :desexed, 
      :microchipped, :microchip_number, :date_missing, :rewald, :image, :adress_lost,
      :name_host, :telephone, :email ])
  end

end
```

**log in terminal:**

```
LostPetsController Get #show assings the requested lost pet to @lost_pet
     Failure/Error: get :show, id: lost_pet
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:656:in `params'
     # ./app/controllers/lost_pets_controller.rb:18:in `load_lost_pet'
```

Why error with wrong number argument for action show? How solve this issue? 
Thank advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your line:

```
@lost_pet = LostPet.find(params(:id))
```

To:

```
@lost_pet = LostPet.find(params[:id])
```

(Notice the square brackets)

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

```
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

means that you are calling a method and supplying one argument, but the method doesn't take any arguments, thus "1 for 0". Which method? It's the first one in the backtrace:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:656:in `params'
```

`params` returns the parameter hash. You can quickly see the cause of the error in the controller:

```
@lost_pet = LostPet.find(params(:id))
```

fix it by using square brackets instead of parens:

```
@lost_pet = LostPet.find(params[:id])
```